# How can I run a js function between 2 times

Tags: javascript, timer, intervals, countdown

I made a countdown timer which runs in regular interval times .ie every hour  but I wanted this timer to run only between 2 times let's say between 5am and 11pm every day.

Comment: You should always share your code whenever possible, if you wish to attract working answers.

Comment: Server's time or client's time?

Answer (score 1):

I think, your timer performs some code every hour, and this could shall only be executed between to times every day. I would make an if-Statement at beginn of the function to check the time at every execution and break execution if the time is not correct, you can cancel the execution.

Answer (score 0):

Without any code, I can only suggest a generic strategy. You should be able to do it by storing the time duration in a variable which is accessible inside the timer function. Then whenever the timer function is invoked, simply check if the current time is within the permitted interval and if so execute the relevant code.